# Disk copying with two OS on it

Tags: upgrade, dd, disk, gparted, cloning

I want to change HDD in my laptop to bigger one. I have installed WIN XP and Mageia Linux and GRUB version 1 as the bootloader.
I want to use procedure, such as below, for copying and changing disk:

- plug new one disk to USB enclose
- boot laptop from LIVE version of Linux Mageia (from DVD)
- connect new HDD to USB port
- run such command

  ```
  dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
  ```
- After copying, plug new one HDD to laptop, replacing older one.
- Boot to check the proper functionality
- boot again from LIVE DVD to use GParted for resizing partitions

Does this look like a correct procedure?

Comment: Yes. It seem to be proper steps

Comment: Just make sure you have the drive letters right, i.e., that the new disk is **really** /dev/sdb. The consequences of an error here might be devastating. Use *fdisk -* if in doubt.

Comment: OH. THX for answers